# "Rfkill list all" doesn't show wifi and "dmesg | grep iwlwifi" shows error

Tags: networking, drivers, 19.10, iwlwifi

Hey guys i have installed ubuntu 19.10 on my new dell inspirion and can not connect to wifi cause ubuntu doesn't see adapter. Also the main problem that i only have WLAN and now cannot connect to Internet.
And when i run ubuntu from iso image and choose try ubuntu it see the adapter and i can connect to wifi but after installing nope(
"rfkill list all": only bluetooth

"dmesg | grep iwlwifi":

`[    2.459723] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.466841] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
[    2.467064] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.535306] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9462, REV=0x354
[    3.563950] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[    3.564326] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    3.564328] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: -779069621
[    3.564329] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 48.4fa0041f.0
[    3.564330] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xACD428D6 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT

[    3.564331] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0389BC7B | trm_hw_status0
[    3.564332] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x89919375 | trm_hw_status1
[    3.564332] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0D0CD264 | branchlink2
[    3.564333] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x098CCA58 | interruptlink1
[    3.564334] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x9912F369 | interruptlink2
[    3.564334] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xCFD95772 | data1
[    3.564335] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0905774F | data2
[    3.564336] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC46DD9B8 | data3
[    3.564336] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD7748C51 | beacon time
[    3.564337] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD64D1B7B | tsf low
[    3.564338] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDA29ED99 | tsf hi
[    3.564338] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA8EC820F | time gp1
[    3.564339] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFB9EBB0C | time gp2
[    3.564340] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x174058B8 | uCode revision type
[    3.564340] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB98D968D | uCode version major
[    3.564341] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x993107C9 | uCode version minor
[    3.564342] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x23EA0A9D | hw version
[    3.564342] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xEC1B9D0E | board version
[    3.564343] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF3D3C98D | hcmd
[    3.564344] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFCDFB0F8 | isr0
[    3.564344] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x414912E3 | isr1
[    3.564345] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x11CFFA09 | isr2
[    3.564346] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xEAD6087E | isr3
[    3.564346] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xBEFCAAB4 | isr4
[    3.564347] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x799E41AD | last cmd Id
[    3.564348] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xAB794BFE | wait_event
[    3.564348] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xCA1DAB55 | l2p_control
[    3.564349] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFDE0C967 | l2p_duration
[    3.564350] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x83A342D0 | l2p_mhvalid
[    3.564350] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x5137F910 | l2p_addr_match
[    3.564351] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x235F3DDD | lmpm_pmg_sel
[    3.564352] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE6C25439 | timestamp
[    3.564352] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x971AB311 | flow_handler
[    3.564414] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    3.564415] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7
[    3.564416] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x201013F1 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[    3.564416] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[    3.564417] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC008CF5C | umac branchlink2
[    3.564418] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
[    3.564418] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[    3.564419] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | umac data1
[    3.564420] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | umac data2
[    3.564421] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000201 | umac data3
[    3.564421] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000030 | umac major
[    3.564422] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4FA0041F | umac minor
[    3.564423] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00005CCC | frame pointer
[    3.564423] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0887F58 | stack pointer
[    3.564424] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[    3.564425] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[    3.564441] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[    3.564444] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    3.564447] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00260000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    3.564450] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    3.564453] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    3.564457] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x5E346558 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    3.564460] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    3.564463] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    3.564467] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000201 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    3.564470] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    3.564476] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000201 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    3.564482] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    3.564535] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    3.564634] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5c3a, CPU2 Status: 0x3
[    3.564635] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[    3.564637] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[    3.576071] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[ 1297.298962] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
[ 1297.299115] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[ 1297.312018] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9462, REV=0x354
[ 1298.348035] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[ 1298.348139] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[ 1298.348147] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: -779069621
[ 1298.348151] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 48.4fa0041f.0
[ 1298.348155] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC8D43392 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT

[ 1298.348159] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0339BC7B | trm_hw_status0
[ 1298.348162] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFDF1937D | trm_hw_status1
[ 1298.348165] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2F0DF88C | branchlink2
[ 1298.348168] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2D4CCACA | interruptlink1
[ 1298.348170] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x9A53F36A | interruptlink2
[ 1298.348173] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6FF85772 | data1
[ 1298.348176] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x3905474E | data2
[ 1298.348179] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC46DD9A2 | data3
[ 1298.348182] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD7740851 | beacon time
[ 1298.348185] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD65D8B7B | tsf low
[ 1298.348188] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDA29E8FD | tsf hi
[ 1298.348190] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA8AF8249 | time gp1
[ 1298.348193] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEC6BF26 | time gp2
[ 1298.348196] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD54FD0FA | uCode revision type
[ 1298.348199] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB98D96ED | uCode version major
[ 1298.348202] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x983197C9 | uCode version minor
[ 1298.348205] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x23E24E9D | hw version
[ 1298.348208] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA40F9D2E | board version
[ 1298.348211] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE7F7C98D | hcmd
[ 1298.348214] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8EDFB05C | isr0
[ 1298.348217] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004912F5 | isr1
[ 1298.348219] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x11CFFA23 | isr2
[ 1298.348222] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFAD6087D | isr3
[ 1298.348225] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x3FFCAA74 | isr4
[ 1298.348228] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x718E4901 | last cmd Id
[ 1298.348231] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA3694B9E | wait_event
[ 1298.348234] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7A5CB255 | l2p_control
[ 1298.348237] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF9E0C967 | l2p_duration
[ 1298.348240] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x83E042C0 | l2p_mhvalid
[ 1298.348242] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7117F91E | l2p_addr_match
[ 1298.348245] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x625F9D59 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[ 1298.348248] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x72C254A3 | timestamp
[ 1298.348251] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x077AF6A1 | flow_handler
[ 1298.348300] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[ 1298.348303] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7
[ 1298.348306] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x201013F1 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[ 1298.348309] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[ 1298.348312] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC008CF5C | umac branchlink2
[ 1298.348315] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
[ 1298.348318] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[ 1298.348321] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | umac data1
[ 1298.348324] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | umac data2
[ 1298.348327] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000201 | umac data3
[ 1298.348330] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000030 | umac major
[ 1298.348333] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4FA0041F | umac minor
[ 1298.348336] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00005D2C | frame pointer
[ 1298.348339] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0887F58 | stack pointer
[ 1298.348342] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[ 1298.348345] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[ 1298.348372] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[ 1298.348391] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[ 1298.348412] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00260000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[ 1298.348433] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[ 1298.348454] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[ 1298.348476] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x5E346558 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[ 1298.348498] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[ 1298.348519] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[ 1298.348541] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000201 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[ 1298.348563] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[ 1298.348587] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000201 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[ 1298.348609] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[ 1298.348660] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[ 1298.348697] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5c89, CPU2 Status: 0x3
[ 1298.348700] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[ 1298.348718] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[ 1298.360083] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110`

"sudo lshw -C network":
`*-network

       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:a1218000-a121bfff`

I tried a lot of ways and they gave nothing. Hope for your helps!