# Intel AC 9560 not working

Tags: drivers, intel, iwlwifi, firmware

So I got a new PC(L13 yoga with Intel AC9560) and I want to install Linux. More specific Ubuntu and for some reason the wifi adapter does not work. In the settings it says it is not found and in the system log there is some funny error.

```
alex@alex-ThinkPad-L13-Yoga:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
[   11.012138] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   11.037095] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
[   11.037274] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   11.168776] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz, REV=0x354
[   12.188157] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[   12.188254] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   12.188256] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: -1965079994
[   12.188257] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 48.4fa0041f.0
[   12.188258] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x5FFFE51B | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[   12.188259] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2DE51C49 | trm_hw_status0
[   12.188260] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x89F71AA3 | trm_hw_status1
[   12.188260] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x3D1C3FAE | branchlink2
[   12.188261] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x44EB7CC4 | interruptlink1
[   12.188262] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xBA5E9200 | interruptlink2
[   12.188262] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4FC1DA70 | data1
[   12.188263] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6F6EFC7B | data2
[   12.188264] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE8FFEE69 | data3
[   12.188264] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD441415B | beacon time
[   12.188265] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC479C522 | tsf low
[   12.188266] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xADC1ADE8 | tsf hi
[   12.188266] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF5FAB2DF | time gp1
[   12.188267] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x031B4B68 | time gp2
[   12.188268] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x131D89FB | uCode revision type
[   12.188268] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x1EAE5E41 | uCode version major
[   12.188269] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x31AA1E23 | uCode version minor
[   12.188269] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2AEF33F6 | hw version
[   12.188270] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA38ECD84 | board version
[   12.188271] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2C1AB01C | hcmd
[   12.188271] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE5C43FA3 | isr0
[   12.188272] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4DC68FF5 | isr1
[   12.188273] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE8551D7B | isr2
[   12.188273] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE6391315 | isr3
[   12.188274] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xBF7E79BD | isr4
[   12.188275] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x745DAECC | last cmd Id
[   12.188275] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFD00C59F | wait_event
[   12.188276] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x9C9E0F50 | l2p_control
[   12.188277] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x69DC3AD6 | l2p_duration
[   12.188277] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xEFA5EFDB | l2p_mhvalid
[   12.188278] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF1937BC2 | l2p_addr_match
[   12.188278] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF508919B | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   12.188279] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4F127DE1 | timestamp
[   12.188280] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xBDA44FAF | flow_handler
[   12.188312] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   12.188313] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7
[   12.188314] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x201013F1 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   12.188315] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   12.188315] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC008CF5C | umac branchlink2
[   12.188316] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
[   12.188317] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[   12.188317] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | umac data1
[   12.188318] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | umac data2
[   12.188319] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | umac data3
[   12.188319] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000030 | umac major
[   12.188320] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4FA0041F | umac minor
[   12.188321] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00005C8E | frame pointer
[   12.188321] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0887F58 | stack pointer
[   12.188322] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[   12.188322] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[   12.188341] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   12.188343] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   12.188345] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00260000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   12.188348] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80020006 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   12.188350] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   12.188352] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x06432BDF | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   12.188354] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   12.188356] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   12.188358] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   12.188361] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   12.188365] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   12.188369] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   12.188403] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   12.188431] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5bfe, CPU2 Status: 0x3
[   12.188432] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[   12.188434] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[   12.200228] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

So I tried both 18.04 and 19.10 and they both do not work. So the output presented here is from 19.10.

```
alex@alex-ThinkPad-L13-Yoga:~$ modinfo iwlwifi 
filename:       /lib/modules/5.3.0-40-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-jf-b0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-cc-a0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-jf-b0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-a0-hr-a0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-hr-b0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-f0-hr-a0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-jf-b0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-hr-a0-48.ucode
srcversion:     263DD85C748F2F7EFAE8CF0
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlwifi
vermagic:       5.3.0-40-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        75:91:66:DF:05:2B:18:0F:1D:65:B1:E2:67:B8:EE:3E:F3:66:8F:EE
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      55:6D:99:09:87:D8:AE:5B:35:0C:2B:BB:0A:38:88:1A:E2:0B:CD:46:
        F1:A3:87:09:65:04:17:99:93:E7:A9:27:F7:B0:97:1D:C0:5E:C0:E4:
        02:88:ED:25:C9:F5:80:77:1B:C1:65:61:46:23:D8:E1:5E:2F:9A:A5:
        2D:75:4D:7A:D0:EF:4A:7E:18:AD:F3:BE:F6:C2:30:8E:74:77:C4:C8:
        68:12:29:49:72:EF:35:BA:03:81:0B:0D:EA:04:D7:87:4D:F6:1A:E6:
        B1:BA:BC:C6:AC:A6:B6:2E:8A:0C:CB:AD:84:F2:5E:92:35:D1:20:DD:
        E6:BC:3D:84:93:02:66:25:64:F0:A5:74:8A:06:63:03:10:D9:64:5F:
        AC:B8:A5:B2:2D:49:79:AC:66:ED:0B:A1:09:26:F7:F0:92:2B:A3:04:
        9A:42:D3:4E:C7:A7:97:CF:B1:76:A1:9A:D7:DC:42:D5:81:EB:7E:3F:
        A6:9A:FC:BA:10:E3:FA:B8:C1:0C:A0:F2:40:8C:D7:71:43:3D:E2:6B:
        0D:00:4C:C8:5D:61:6A:45:FF:C8:88:64:5C:17:7B:2F:FD:E4:48:9E:
        F2:C6:52:3C:6A:A3:2A:A8:12:15:8B:96:C2:64:2A:85:4D:4A:C3:86:
        3C:C3:7D:CC:9B:CA:DD:D8:E7:FD:31:9B:8E:89:48:0E:B4:10:F7:F0:
        E2:98:5F:35:8F:BA:47:9E:AB:84:85:D6:D3:12:86:E1:A7:98:24:D3:
        42:8A:7F:9C:D1:F1:BC:FC:A3:05:4F:C1:45:79:C1:D4:16:B5:80:42:
        93:E1:B3:80:F0:7F:30:7B:9F:D4:A6:64:A2:5B:D4:23:79:7B:3E:28:
        37:44:EA:33:CB:EC:A2:DE:CE:4F:3A:0F:97:AF:85:74:53:28:5E:76:
        5D:6E:AC:7D:47:A6:17:CB:43:48:FA:D4:56:1D:01:F9:44:18:96:DC:
        E7:AA:AB:A8:47:E2:0E:B4:7A:87:4F:D3:98:4A:63:B9:ED:BF:52:FD:
        43:F7:6E:66:74:0F:0A:ED:47:C4:55:5A:DA:0F:25:CF:B0:46:D9:3C:
        14:CD:23:F6:AD:9B:49:9B:77:A9:E1:95:BF:E6:A7:E0:9A:3C:D6:07:
        BB:89:01:B6:45:DF:0F:17:4A:57:B8:04:53:01:A7:1F:AC:6B:E5:E9:
        1F:68:D9:39:57:6F:6B:DA:4F:AE:DB:50:A4:5C:7E:12:C8:19:DE:CD:
        0C:79:85:99:91:43:7E:39:80:2F:CB:F9:4B:AE:06:E0:14:A9:AD:59:
        1A:84:AE:C3:75:DC:F6:7D:F7:FA:20:E8:75:4A:E0:45:2D:C4:07:BB:
        BA:90:81:DA:92:16:EB:47:E0:2C:EE:EB
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 2K for 22560 devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K 4: 2K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           enable_ini:Enable debug INI TLV FW debug infrastructure (default: 0 (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)
parm:           d0i3_timeout:Timeout to D0i3 entry when idle (ms) (uint)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm:           remove_when_gone:Remove dev from PCIe bus if it is deemed inaccessible (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_11ax:Disable HE capabilities (default: false) (bool)
```

```
alex@alex-ThinkPad-L13-Yoga:~$ sudo rfkill list all
[sudo] password for alex: 
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

So I updated Linux-firmware package did not help. Now the funny part if I boot from a USB drive in the live version of both 18.04 and 19.10 it works.

Intel says this chip is supported by the kenerel since 4.14 and I got 5.3. https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html

How can I find out more about this? What could I try?

Comment: Similar error to this one https://askubuntu.com/questions/1212335/rfkill-list-all-doesnt-show-wifi-and-dmesg-grep-iwlwifi-shows-error

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu and Stack Exchange! Have you used `modprobe` for `iwlwifi-9000`? It is the driver for your Wi-Fi card. Found on [wiki.kernel.org](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi) EDIT: Use `sudo modprobe iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46`

Comment: Please run `sudo modprobe iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46` in a non-eleavated terminal (no `#`).

Comment: I would but I already installed fedora which solved my issue and I am not so keen on going back again :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up installing fedora 31 works there, has kernel 5.5

Comment: Good that that worked! For whatever reason my final answer was converted to a comment.

Comment: I am now using Ubuntu 20.04 that also works since they updated the kernel version.